# How do I unlock the Showcase?

Tags: pocket-clothier

The game told me to "Keep developing", but it's been years now and I still don't have the Showcase for displaying end-game clothes.

How do I unlock the Showcase?

Answer (score 2):

Showcase - Have a Staff Member with 300 Taste