# How do I get Showcases?

Tags: pocket-clothier

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I unlock the Showcase?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72934/how-do-i-unlock-the-showcase)

I have a few high end clothing items that require a Showcase in order for me to sell them. I am reasonably sure this is something my employees can research in my Idea Rooms, but I have been researching for years now with no Showcase to show for it.

How do I get Showcases?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72934/how-do-i-unlock-the-showcase?

Comment: ...right then. Search fail. VTC as dupe, everyone!